# Apply filter to matrix based on value' slicer of its own values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Would like to ask for any related help with my issue

There is a measure Fullness:

```
Fullness = 
    SWITCH(
        SELECTEDVALUE('Stock type'[Stocks type]),
        "Stock Fact + Stock on the way", SUMX(
            'Stock',
            DIVIDE(
                'Stock'[GroupWeight] * 'Stock'[Stock pcs] * 'Stock'[Capacity],
                SUM('Cap'[Capacity])
            )
        ) + SUM('Cap'[Capacity]) * 0,
        "Stock Fact", SUMX(
            'Stock',
            DIVIDE(
                'Stock'[GroupWeight] * 'Stock'[Stock fact] * 'Stock'[Capacity],
                SUM('Cap'[Capacity])
            )
        ) + SUM('Cap'[Capacity]) * 0
    )
```

which calculates Fullness value in two scenarios based on selected value in slicer (table with just two options - "Stock Fact + Stock on the way" or "Stock Fact"). It is ok that values can be more than 100%.

There is a matrix with Stores as rows and Departments as columns
[Fullness measure output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjFaL.png)

There are many tables in my model, but main ones involved in current calculation are [Tables relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVHoC.png)

The issue is to add value range slicer that able to filter only those Stores/Departments which meets slicer condition. For example, if we set slicer value to 0.4 (40%), matrix should show only those Stores/Dept-s Fullness values of those are less then 40%.

I added parameter as a slicer, implying that 1 is 100% and increment is 10%

```
Parameter = GENERATESERIES(0.1, 1, 0.1)
```

```
Value Parameter = SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter'[Parameter])
```

I have tried to handle it also with SELECTEDVALUE, but didnt get expected result so far..

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a range slicer then you won't get a result from `SELECTEDVALUE`. `SELECTEDVALUE` only returns a value if only one value is found.

You need to capture the min/max. Try something like:

```
  var minSlice = MIN('Parameter'[Parameter])
  var maxSlice = MAX('Parameter'[Parameter])
  var result = [Fullness]
  return IF(minSlice <= result && result <= maxSlice, result)
```

Comment: Thank you Sam for quick response and useful solution! By the way, i wonder, what can be useful for handling values that more than 100%? Lets say we have to add classic percent slicer (with value 100% as an end value). But once we set maximum value in it, values more then 100% not included in output. At the same time i should keep 100% as an end value for range slicer, or at least add one more step something like "100+" that will include all these values over 100%. Any idea how to add it? My guess is to create new table/column with values similar to previous  (0-0.1 .. 0.9 -1 - 1+)..

Comment: Easiest would be to keep it as it is and do a check for if max is 1 then include 1 and above. `&& (result <= maxSlice || maxSlice = 1)`

Comment: I have a struggle with implementing this logic into "IF" expression :( Seems i have to add additional condition for values equal 1 and above, right?

Comment: `IF(minSlice <= result && (result <= maxSlice || maxSlice = 1), result)` which is saying the maxice is 1 (100%) then no upper limit.

Comment: I did absolutely same. however displayed values are still same( .
If it edited manually for example. to 0-2 (200%), these can be shown
https://imgur.com/a/NYIMtyu

Comment: Seems there is a precision issue. Select the `'Parameter'[Parameter]` column and change its Data type from `Decimal` to `Fixed decimal` in `Column tools` tab in the ribbon, then it will work. Or update the conditional to: `IF(minSlice <= result && (result <= maxSlice || maxSlice > 0.99), result)`

Comment: Didn't know that it is a working thing (change format to Fixed decimal), interesting. Both your suggestions works very well Sam! I would like to apply first one, i think it is more rational. Thank you one more time!